# Github change github page to github project page

Tags: git, github, dns, github-pages

I already have a github page (username.github.io) that will jump to my godaddy domain.

But I also need to create another github page in the format username.github.io for a homework assignment.

Is there anyway I can host my original github page under some sort of github project page (username.github.io/projectname) so that I can clear my github page (username.github.io) for use for my hw assignment, WHILE PRESERVING all the commits I previously made?

DNS changes takes too long to propagate so I'm afraid to mess up.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `username.github.io` repository to whatever you want the project page to be, make sure your [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) resolution is set up correctly, and then create a new repository with the name `username.github.io`.